# Unity3d sharpPDF plugin different color of rows and cells

Tags: unity-game-engine, pdf-generation, sharppdf

I am using sharpPDF plugin in Unity.

I see that there is `.rowStyle` and `.alternateRowStyle` in there, but I need all rows (or even maybe cells) to be different color. For example first row should be Red, second should be Blue, third should be Yellow etc.

Is that possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us with your code? I don't use sharpPDF and never have, but if I can see something I might be able to work something out. Do you know how to set the color of a row?

Comment: `pdfTableRow myRow = myTable.createRow();

myRow[0].columnValue = "1";

myRow[1].columnValue = "Correct";

myTable.addRow(myRow);
myTable.rowStyle = new pdfTableRowStyle(predefinedFont.csCourier,8,new pdfColor(predefinedColor.csBlack),new pdfColor(predefinedColor.csLightGreen));

myTable.alternateRowStyle = new pdfTableRowStyle(predefinedFont.csCourier,8,new pdfColor(predefinedColor.csBlack),new pdfColor(predefinedColor.csLightRed));`

Comment: You're explaining a table inside of your question, but you're asking about a PDF document, are you trying to create a table inside of the PDF? === You edited that really fast, lol, put the code in your original question using the `edit` feature so it's formatted.

Comment: Check to see if myRow[1].rowStyle is available

Comment: Clicked enter accidently.

I am making a PDF with a table in Unity. I have to make some kind of statistic for a quiz.

All questions have to be in separate rows, and if it was answered correctly it should be green, and if not, it should be red.

Comment: Not available like that.

Comment: May I ask why you're using sharpPDF for this? Is it required, or just a solution you thought of?

Comment: It is not required. Any other suggestions? I am opened for everything atm :)

Comment: It would be very simple using the new UI, I could write the code for you if you'd like, but you'd have to download Unity 4.6.

Comment: You could export PDF file like that?

Comment: No, I was under the impression that you were just trying to display a table, you'd be suprised the amount of work-arounds people have used with the old UI System. I've searched high and low through the documents of sharpPDF, but I can't find any way to change the rows color by itself.

Comment: Another solution would be iTextSharp, here's an example doing what you'd like -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053963/add-header-footer-and-background-color-to-pdf-cells-in-itextsharp

Comment: Yeah, it is required to export PDF file. I will take a look at iTextSharp. Can it be used on all platforms (iOS, android, windows phone, PC, Mac, Web)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I don't personally use it.